# Exporting toolbox from ArcGIS 10.5 (Python 2.7) to ArcGIS 9.3 (Python 2.5)?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, export

I built an interface using ArcGIS 10.5.0 with Python ver. 2.7, I want to export this toolbox to an other PCs that using ArcGIS 9.3 with Python ver. 2.5.

I did it using Toolbox save as but the toolbox seems to be empty.

Comment: I ***seriously*** doubt this is possible. Python support was in its infancy at 9.3, as was Python, and there just isn't any *there* to which to export.

Comment: And even Python 2.7 is becoming obsolete by the end of this year (https://pythonclock.org/). Staying with Python2.7 is not a good idea, going backwards seems even worse. Sooner rather than later ESRI will have to start using 3.x for ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: It's not fiction, it's a bitter reality!
We are now a working group to prepare a land use map for the entire territory of our State.
A number of my colleagues are still using ARCGIS 9.3. The latest versions can not be downloaded on their computers because they are too old and the user license can not be obtained for the whole team. So we rub our heads and noses to circumvent the LUCS program I designed on version 10.5

Comment: This map must be done at a scale of 1: 50,000 (SYRIAN LUCS), at very low cost to use these maps in land use planning for post-war reconstruction. There is no escape from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Vince, it would be futile to attempt to convert the code backwards to such an old version of ArcMap. The modern `arcpy` module never existed then it use to be a `gp` object which you can find out about at [Geoprocessor programming model](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Geoprocessor_programming_model). It would be a major rewrite to make it compatible. Also the language python has evolved so what you have used in 10.5 may have no equivalent in the python that existed for 9.3.

Also from what I remember the original geoprocessor used to dish out enumerators but to fall in line with python standards things are now dished out in list objects.